# How do you mathematically add and subtract hash power?

Tags: hash, hashpower

My question was how do you mathematically add and subtract hash power. I recently purchased four Antminer D3s.They all run at the average rate of 19-20 MH/s but when I go to my stats in the pool that I joined I see 32.2 GH/s. Please Help!!!

Comment: 19-20 MH/s doesn't seem right; marketing quotes seem to be on the order of 15 GH/s per unit.

Answer (score 1):

You sum (add) their individual ratings. For example, if I had two miners, one rated at 20MH/s and another rated at 15MH/s, my total rate would be 20MH/s + 15MH/s = 35MH/s.